# Show Redirect URI on the Google API Console

Tags: oauth-2.0

I am looking for the proper Redirect URIs while using Google's OAuth2 libraries. I am getting a "Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Missing scheme: /" error and it seems that I am not setting the proper Redirect URI.

However when I go to https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials which is where I am supposed to set my Redirect URIs, there is nowhere that I can set any sort of Redirect URI. It's just blank.

How do I set the Redirect URI if this option isn't available under the credentials page?

[image: where are my redirect uri options?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about adding new credential? The method is as follows.

1. Click "Create credentials" as OAuth client ID.
2. Check "Web application".
3. Input your Redirect URI at "Authorized redirect URIs".
4. Click "Create".
5. Copy the Client ID and Client Secret. They are used for OAuth2 process.

If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.